# Inno Uninstall delete files

Tags: inno-setup

I have an installer, using InnoSetup, that does all the installing/uninstall, basically correct. I say basically because the uninstall isn't doing quite everything I want it do.

We had, `.pdb` files go out in a version(s), of our install without our knowledge. So, now, when doing an uninstall, those files do not get deleted. I have the admin rights set, using:

`PrivilegesRequired=admin`

And I'm deleting the folder structure like:

```
[UninstallDelete]
;; Delete service logs
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\main log folder\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_1\*";
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_2\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_3\*";
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_4\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_5\*";
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_6\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_7\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_8\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_9\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_10\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_11\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_12\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_13\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_14\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_15\*";
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_16\*";
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{commonappdata}\old logs loc_17\*";

;; Delete old files and Service dlls
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\Comp-any, ltd\folder\*";
```

I'm left with basically all of the folder structure left under the `main log folder` folder. It has a structure of `main log folder\new log loc_1\` ect. for all (up to 17) services.

**Is there anything else I can do to delete those files?** When I go in to delete them manually, it ask for admin privileges to delete each one so I'm not really sure what's going on.

I have looked at this flag: `uninsrestartdelete`, on the inno setup page, but we don't want to require users to restart after uninstalling our software.

Comment: I'm aware that users could chose a different install location so files may not be removed. Don't worry about that factor.

Comment: Do I understand right the the problem is that subfolders of the `main log folder` are not deleted? How are those subfolders created? Are there any records regarding those subfolders in the uninstaller log file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, yes they are not getting deleted. There are also folders under the `"{app}\Comp-any, ltd\folder\*"` that are not getting deleted. I am running an install quick to find out about the uninstall log file. I'll get back to you. The folders are created in the `[Files]` section of the inno installer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, well, considering I attempt to delete files out of the location where the unintall log would go, I don't have at the moment. It'll take me a while to make a new installer to get one.

Comment: Just run the uninstaller manually, specifying the `/log=c:\some\other\path\uninstall.log` on its command-line.